# How to resolve invalid JAVA CLASS in OWBSYS user

Tags: oracle, etl, data-warehouse

I am getting some invalid java object after running the following select statement.

```
select OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE, STATUS  from ALL_OBJECTS where status='INVALID' and owner='OWBSYS';
```

```
OBJECT_NAME OBJECT_TYPE STATUS
--------------- ------------------------------ ------------------- -------
/11d72cdd_TaskScheduler JAVA CLASS INVALID
/12b895ae_LexiComparator JAVA CLASS INVALID
/1327ed5a_LRUCacheLRUNode JAVA CLASS INVALID
/1aabcc3f_ServiceDoctor JAVA CLASS INVALID
/1dad730_NAMsgUtilComponentInf JAVA CLASS INVALID
/1ef21df6_NameAddrRes_ko JAVA CLASS INVALID
/20dd1937_ImmutableArray JAVA CLASS INVALID
/235a039f_NameAddrExceptions_e JAVA CLASS INVALID
/23c25276_UnhandledException JAVA CLASS INVALID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter the java class with RESOLVE clause

```
Connect to OWBSYS user
```

Then execute the following statement.

```
SQL> ALTER JAVA CLASS "<java class>" RESOLVE;
```